# How to include 3rd party module (angular-pull-to-refresh), which has no type definitions

Tags: angularjs, module, pull-to-refresh

I'm a complete beginner and I don't have any idea, how include libraries and inject module, so please, bear with me.
This is the module I want to include: https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-pull-to-refresh

I installed module with bower and successfully linked them.  and  should be in app.component.html right? Or should I link it in component named list (`list.component.html`) where I show data, which I want to refresh with pulldown?

Could you point me in the right direction, where to put this line and what exactly does 'myApp' represent here.
- Inject the `mgcrea.pullToRefresh` module into your app:
`angular.module('myApp', ['mgcrea.pullToRefresh']);`

And at the example, `pull-to-refresh` attribute is called and within function onReload(). Where should this function be located?

Thank you all for reading and helping me!

Comment: You should do yourself a favor and take some kind of course that covers building an Angularjs app from scratch so you've got all the fundamental knowledge to know how to search for the answers you need when you need them, read the documentation for meaningful insights, and so on. This is a great place to start. https://toddmotto.com/angularjs/  StackOverflow is the place to go for very specific questions where you can show in detail what you've tried so people can help with very specific issues.

Comment: First of all: Why do you need this module? I'm asking because it seems to be an old module (last commit from 5 years and it use bower. Bower is deprecated now).
Are you starting a new project? if yes, why do you want to use angularjs (angularjs was a great js framework 4 years ago).

I need this info to answer the question

Comment: I don't need this specific module, I'm fine with any pull-to-refresh module. For my project I'm using Angular 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to get working pull to refresh with this plugin: https://github.com/BoxFactura/pulltorefresh.js
This is how:
Install plugin and @types for plugin with
`npm install pulltorefreshjs --save
npm install @types/pulltorefreshjs --save`

And then importing it in app.components.ts
`import * as PullToRefresh from 'pulltorefreshjs';`

And initializing it in app.components.ts:
`ptrinit:any = PullToRefresh.init();`

Answer (score 0):

According to the website you can do it like this, in your js file:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', ['mgcrea.pullToRefresh']);

   angular.module('myApp')
   .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $q) {

   $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas'];

   $scope.onReload = function() {
      console.warn('reload');
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve(true);
      }, 1000);
      return deferred.promise;
   };

});
```

In your index.html file:

```
<body ontouchstart="" ng-controller="AppCtrl">

<div class="content">
    <ul class="list-group list-group-table" pull-to-refresh="onReload()">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="state in states" ng-bind="state"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

By adding the **ng-controller directive** in the **body tag** of your page, you are telling which part of your page will be handled by which controller. In this case the **AppCtrl** controller. You can have more than one controller responsible for different sections of your page, like divs, body or one controller responsible for the entire page, like the html tags.

Hope this help!